# API Call acting differently in different environments

Tags: c#, winapi

This is a difficult one to figure out. We have a solution that includes a User Application and a WCF Service that use the same back end business layer code to create API calls to an external application. Most of the API calls happen just fine from either the two work flows. However, one specific API call does not work correctly in the WCF Service bit.

Essentially, my question is why would an API call work in a User Application that tests the API call, basically running the process from the UI, and not when it is called from the Service layer (an automated process). We are trying to login to an application and the API calls are working from our User Interface which builds the back end process, but when it is running through the automated process, the API call is not working.

Have any of you run across this particular issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Specifically the SendMessage API call sending the WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR and WM_KEYUP messages. public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, [Out] int wParam, string lParam);

Comment: Probably because the service is running on a none UI mode in with the WM_KEYDOWN message don't exist.

Comment: It is set up with the Interact With Desktop mode checked on. The terminal session is set to 0. We are using the above events to actually set the User ID and Password and we are seeing those work just fine. It's when we send the Space bar to the Login button where we have an issue.

Comment: Look at ChangeWindowMessageFilter after vista service and process have some message filtered out.

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means Cat. However, here is a different question. We have a User interface that designs a workflow of data through a downstream application. The work flow when tested from that User Interface works with the application just fine. However, the work flow from the automated Service does not. Does the UI bypass the Terminal Session 0 parameter somehow?

Comment: Since vista the messages send between Services and UI are default drop by the system. So you need to change the message filter on the receiving process to make it accept the specific message you sent.